# Ionic 2/3 How to access values in a Radio Alert

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2, alert, ionic3

I'm using JavaScript with Ionic 3 and working on iOS. I'm trying to implement a Alert with Radio options for the user to select from.

I can’t get to use/access the selected Radio values in an Alert in the following code:

```
   let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Specify the reason',
        inputs: [
          {
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'label 1',
            value: '0'
          },
          {
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'label 2',
            value: '1'
          }
        ],
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: () => {
              console.log('Cancel clicked');
            }
          },
          {
            text: 'OK',
            handler: () => {
              console.log('OK clicked: ' );
              // I NEED TO GET THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED RADIO BUTTON HERE
            }
          }
        ]
      });
      alert.present();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the data in the OK handler:

```
inputs: [
    {
        name: "myValue", // add a name property
        type: 'radio',
        label: 'label 1',
        value: '0'
    },
    {
        name: "myValue", // and here
        type: 'radio',
        label: 'label 2',
        value: '1',
    }
],
buttons: [
    {
        text: 'OK',
        handler: data => {
            console.log('OK clicked: ');
            // access through 'data.[nameproperty]'
            console.log(data.myValue);
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You do get the radio data in your handler. Check [the docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#alert-radio)..Your Ok handler will have the data as parameter.

```
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'OK',
        handler: (radiobuttonData) => {
          console.log('OK clicked: '+ radiobuttonData );//here
        }
      }
    ]
```